# C - Statements not executing in order

Tags: c, compiler-errors, gtk, execution

I have the following code which I am trying to run, however the `wait_for_connection()` appears to be being run before the preceding 2 lines, and I can't seem to understand why? I really need the two preceding lines to be run before the `wait_for_connection()` function is called. Even if I enter a `sleep(1)` before calling the `wait_for_connection()` function, it is still run before the preceding lines.

My code is as follows:

```
void wait_for_connection() {

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        g_print("Checking server...\n");
        if (connected == 1) {
            g_print("Connected to: %s", selectedServerStr);
            break;
        }

        sleep(1);
    }

}

int connect_server(GtkButton *button, gpointer user_data) {

    .......

    if (gtk_tree_selection_get_selected(GTK_TREE_SELECTION(selectedServer), &model, &iter)) {
        path = gtk_tree_model_get_path(model, &iter);
        serverIndex = *gtk_tree_path_get_indices(path);
        g_print("Selected Server IP: %s\n", serverIPArray[serverIndex][0]);

        gtk_widget_set_sensitive(serverList, FALSE);              // These 2 lines needs to be run first
        append_to_log("Attemping connection, please wait...", 1);

        wait_for_connection();  // This is where the error lies, this runs before the above 2 lines

        return 1;
    } else {
        gtk_widget_set_name(serverBox, "fieldsError");
        g_print("No server selected: Aborting...\n");
        return -1;
    }
}
```

The line `gtk_widget_set_sensitive()` is used to disable user interaction of a selection widget, however this doesn't seem to happen until after the `wait_for_connection()` function has finished printing "Checking server..." 10 times. The value `connected` is 0, so currently the function just print "Checking server..." 10 times.

Does anyone have any idea as to what may be happening? Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Assuming no threads, the code *is* executing in order. (Even with threads, each thread executes in order.)

Comment: How do you detect that the `wait_for_connection` call happens before the "above 2 lines"? By checking the output? By stepping through your code in a debugger? If you check the output, and the output is written to `stdout` (using e.g. `printf`) then remember that it's by default *line buffered* and won't actually be printed until the buffer is full or you print a newline. So either use a debugger to see what *really* happens, or add some trailing newlines to your output.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude So the `gtk_widget_set_sensitive()` line is used to disable a widget within the GUI, and this doesn't happen until after the `wait_for_connection()` function finishes printing it's 10 "Checking server..." lines, and then obviously the `g_print` statement appears after that

Comment: regarding: `if (connected == 1)`  Where is `connected` being set?

Comment: @user3629249 `connected` is set at the start of the file, and is set at value 1 just for testing

Answer (score 3):

GUI applications on almost all platforms are event-driven. They need their event-handling functions to execute at regular interval, or the user-interface will seem unresponsive and maybe even seem like it locks up or nothing is happening.

In your `wait_for_connection` you have a loop which can iterate up to ten times, and each iteration you will do `sleep(1)` which sleeps a whole second. While this loop is iterating and sleeping, the event-handling will not happen, and as mentioned that will make it seem like your user-interface is unresponsive and doesn't do anything.

You need to modify your code to be event-driven as well, so the "connection" status will be sent as an event that you can handle, or somehow make the polling asynchronous so it happens in parallel to the event-handling.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have tried using a separate thread to run the `wait_for_connection` function, and this allows for the program to run as expected, however I need to original function to not continue any further, and wait for the result of the `wait_for_connection` function, and am struggling to achieve this, without the original issue occuring again... I apologise, I'm rather new to C and GTK, so I'm still trying to wrap my head around this all

Comment: It's a state-machine.  If you need code x to wait for time-consuming code y to complete, x must be another event-handler that is run by an event/signal/message issued by y.  You must not wait in GUI event-handlers.